# How can I encrypt a message in Perl to decrypt it in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, perl, encryption, integrity

I am needing to encrypt using Perl and decrypt on .Net (C#). i.e. Perl encrypts a file and my .Net code decrypts the file (and even maybe validates integrity).

The problem is that I am not familiar with the encryption capabilities of Perl. Can anyone offer guidance on how best to approach this and what the possibilities are?

Thanks in advance!

DC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Lars said, AES is probably the best choice these days. For a Perl implementation, see [Crypt::Rijndael](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt::Rijndael)

Answer (score 7):

Use AES encryption with a common secret key.

[Perl](http://www.google.no/search?hl=no&q=AES+perl&btnG=Google-s%C3%B8k&meta=&aq=f&oq=)

[C#](http://www.google.no/search?hl=no&safe=off&q=AES+c%23&btnG=S%C3%B8k&meta=)

Comment: Sorry for unmarking your answer. Unfortunately I can't mark both of you with the correct answer - and Leon mentioned Crypt::Rijndael which helped.